# strong mutation control *and* named optional arguments

Tags: programming, language

I love purely functional languages like haskell and erlang, because of their strong control over mutation, but there are practical aspects of them I really don't like. Specifically, I think it's ridiculous that neither has support for named optional arguments to functions like python has. Named optional arguments are ridiculously ridiculously useful. I honestly think they are the number one reason people like python so much. They are obviously compatible with the idea of strong mutation control, so is there a language out there with strong mutation control *and* named optional arguments?

As a preemptive response to the pedantic weenies who will say that haskell actually *does* have support for named optional arguments, I have seen what constitutes such a thing in haskell (https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Optional-Args-Library/blob/master/src/Data/Optional.hs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781096/is-there-a-better-way-to-have-optional-arguments-in-haskell or http://neilmitchell.blogspot.ca/2008/04/optional-parameters-in-haskell.html for example) and it's massively fugly compared to python. [Ditto, erlang.](https://gist.github.com/ibnfirnas/cd39cd48ba94035235f0)

I understand that haskell's strict one input, one output approach to functions is probably incompatible with the idea of optional arguments, as  implemented in python, but I think this one in, one out approach is much more of a nerdy mathy doing-things-because-we-can kind of thing than it is an actually useful language feature. Go ahead and ask me why somewhere else, but the point is whatever replacement I seek does not have to (and probably couldn't) work under the same one input, one output principle and I am completely OK with that.

Answer (score 1):

A quick web search revealed this page at Rosetta Code with code samples in a number of languages: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters

I would rather have left this as a comment, but lack of reputation dictates that it becomes an answer instead. I might as well elaborate:

I have first-hand experience of only a few of these, so I can't say for sure which ones fit in to your other requirements.
**Common Lisp** and **Racket** are two from this list that I have tried myself and that I consider to be somewhat friendly to an immutable programming style. **Clojure** is in there too, but with no "native" support for named parameters (although there is an example of implementing it in **Scheme** on the very same page, so you could probably implement it in Clojure as well, has it has closures and macros).

There is also **F#**, which I have not tried but which has both named and optional parameters according to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/parameters-and-arguments#named-arguments). My understanding is that this is a language that has some philosophical similarities to Haskell.

---

I guess my answer is **F#**, or one of many **Lisp** flavors.